# I got an error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in c++ and i'm trying to make a program to check car license.
Don't make fun out of this code, i already know it's the most inefficient code ever XD. Problem is that i want to make if statement(in the end of code) to verify if every string index is as it should be. Problem is that when i tried to run this program i got error message "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"for the line where is the last if statement. What i should do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    bool check;
    bool check1;
    bool check2;
    bool check3;
    bool check4;
    bool check5;
    bool check6;
    bool check7;
    bool check8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        if (s[0] >= 'A' && s[0] <= 'Z'){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check = false;


        }
        return check;
    }

    for (int q = 0; q < 1; q++){
        if (s[1] >= 'A' && s[1] <= 'Z'){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check1 = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check1 = false;

        }
        return check1;
    }

    for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++){
        if (s[2] == '-'){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check2 = true;


        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check2 = false;

        }
        return check2;
    }

    for (int e = 0; e < 1; e++){
        if (isdigit(s[3])){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check3 = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check3 = false;

        }
        return check3;
    }

    for (int e = 0; e < 1; e++){
        if (isdigit(s[4])){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check4 = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check4 = false;

        }
        return check4;
    }

    for (int e = 0; e < 1; e++){
        if (isdigit(s[5])){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check5 = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check5 = false;

        }
        return check5;
    }
         for (int r = 0; r < 1; r++){
                if (s[6] == '-'){
//                cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
                check6 = true;
    }else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check6 = false;

        }
        return check6;
    }
    for (int u = 0; u < 1; u++){
        if (s[7] >= 'A' && s[7] <= 'Z'){
//            cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;
            check7 = true;
          }  

        else {
//           cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check7 = false;
       }
        return check7;
        }
            for (int z = 0; z < 1; z++){
                if (s[8] >= 'A' && s[8] <= 'Z'){
               /*cout << "Dobra tablica" << endl;*/
                check8 = true;

        }
        else {
//            cout << "Losa tablica" << endl;
            check8 = false;
        }
                return check8;

}    



    if(check = true || check1 = true || check2 = true || check3 = true || check4 = true || check5 = true || check6 = true || check7 = true || check8 = true){ // This line of code have an error: "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"
        cout << "Dobra tablica";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Losa tablica";
    }

}
```

Comment: Checking for equality uses "=="; "=" is assignment.

Comment: It's going to be more likely that someone will help you if you point out exactly which line of your program the error message gets reported against, instead of expecting everyone to look through your entire program, looking for the actual problem.

Comment: Why don't you initialize any of your variables when you create them?

Comment: One good way to encourage people to make fun of your code is to ask them not to do it. :) One good way to discourage people from making fun of your code is to not overshare (see [mcve]). You could replace your `for` loops with a comment like "`// Some code to set the above variables`". You get the same compiler error, and there is much less reading/work for the people *volunteering* to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the last if/else block (line 142), you're assigning value "=" instead of checking the boolean "==".

None of the check* variables are initialized so it will pop warnings.
You should initialize them to false.

Lastly, instead of doing `if (check == true)` prefer the following syntax `if (check)`
It does the same thing but it's a lighter syntax (and you could have avoided the assignment error).

Comment: `If (check = true)` will generate a warning with most compilers with suitable compiler settings.